# jQuery click not getting picked up

Tags: html, jquery

I have a input in a td and the click script is not getting picked up and im not sure why? There are no errors in the console.

```
<td>
    <input type="button" class="edit btn btn-primary" value="Edit"></input>
</td>
```

Script below:

```
<script>
    $('.edit').click(function () {
        console.log("Test")
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Your code runs fine with jQuery loaded. Do you have jQuery loaded on your web page?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: `console.log($('.edit').length)` Is it 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'click' even listener might run before the .edit element is rendered to the page. maybe wrap it in a document ready function to ensure it doesn't run till the page is loaded. like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').click(function () {
    console.log("Test")
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `jquery.js` file first like this.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.edit').click(function () {
        console.log("Test")
    })
</script>
```